# How can I create my own Material module using Angular Material 2?

Tags: angular-material2

I was checking the latest release of [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) and in the [release note](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) they said MaterialModule has been marked as deprecated.
here are the words from release note.

> **MaterialModule**
>
> MaterialModule (and MaterialRootModule) have been marked as
>   deprecated. We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking
>   in the world, that using an aggregate NgModule like MaterialModule
>   leads to tools not being able to eliminate code for components that
>   aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size
>   possible, we're deprecating MaterialModule, to be removed in the a
>   subsequent release.
>
> **To replace MaterialModule, users can create their own "Material"
>   module within their application** (e.g., GmailMaterialModule) that
>   imports only the set of components actually used in the application._

So now MaterialModule is deprecated, i think i should not write it in the `imports` array of NgModules( please correct me if i am wrong ). Then how do i use `<md-card>` , `md-button` and other components. The release note says *user can make their own Material module* what does that mean.

can anyone show me a demo of how can i create my own material module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the future commits to master where they update the docs. 
https://github.com/angular/material2/compare/2.0.0-beta.3...master

### Step 3: Import the component modules

**Add MaterialModule as an import in your app's root NgModule.**

Import the NgModule for each component you want to use:

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule]
})
```

So in short, you need to separately specify components in the NgModel which you would like to use instead of one core module. This is done to remove redundant/unused code from the bundle when generating production build.

Comment: This is how you actually should create your own Material Module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688413/how-to-create-a-custom-angular-material-module-material-v2-0-0-beta-3
Not saying that your answer don't work but doesn't answers the question.