# How to create a custom Angular Material module?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was importing the Material library into the base module, app.module.ts, but Angular Material v2.0.0-beta.3 deprecates the Material module.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) you should now create a custom module that imports the individual Material components. I cannot make this work.

This approach:

```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MdInputModule ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdInputModule
  ],
  exports: [ MdInputModule ]
})

export class FooMaterialModule {}
```

Causes this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'MdInputModule' declared by the module 'FooMaterialModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

How do I make a custom module for the Angular Material library?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your custom Angular Material module can mirror the [deprecated Material Module](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/4b3d3d5640f4b8e1b6e96cdbff22692dc7714fdd/src/lib/module.ts).

As the change log indicates, you would want to comment out Material components not used by your application.

> We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking in the world,
>   that using an aggregate NgModule like MaterialModule leads to tools
>   not being able to eliminate code for components that aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size
>   possible, we're deprecating MaterialModule, to be removed in the a
>   subsequent release.
>
> To replace MaterialModule, users can create their own "Material"
>   module within their application (e.g., GmailMaterialModule) that
>   imports only the set of components actually used in the application.

### my-material.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule,
  ]
})
export class MyMaterialModule {}
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

import { MyMaterialModule } from './my-material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,

    ...

    MyMaterialModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a feature module that looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MdInputModule
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule { }
```

Then import it in your app.module.ts:

```
import {CustomMaterialModule} from "./custom-material/custom-material.module";
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    CustomMaterialModule
  ]
  ...
})
```