# Importing a lot of modules in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, import, material-design

I'm building an app with Angular 4 and Angular Material, each Material directive requires me to import its module separately..

For example, i'm building a navigation bar, this is how the `nav.module.ts` starts to look like:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NavComponent} from './nav.component';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome/angular-font-awesome';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    ....
```

There are only 3 Material modules right now, i will need to add more later and except Material, there are also other modules that need to be imported...

Just started moving from AngularJS to Angular4 it feels to me like i'm doing something wrong... Is there a better way to import all the modules? Is my approach to structuring the app is wrong?

Comment: Create a separated module that imports the required Angular Material Modules. This module can be imported into other modules. Take a look at the `MyMaterialModule` in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700125/6942210

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a "shared" module that exports each of the Material Design modules that you need. Then you can simply import the "shared" module into your other modules that need them.

Here is an example:

[image]

In this picture I have a shared module that is exporting CommonModule and FormsModule. The ProductModule then imports the SharedModule to get all of the functionality provided by the CommonModule and FormsModule.

I have a youtube video about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Comment: What do you consider a better practice - using big/long Shared Modules, that have a lot of imports, or using a lot of smaller ones?
And i have to thank you for the video, made a lot of things clear for me, not just the imports :)

Comment: You are welcome! And it really depends. If you have a number of modules that need a large set of third party modules, putting them all in one large shared module makes sense. Then they are easy to find and maintain. If, on the other hand, some modules need different subsets, then separating them may make sense.