# separate module for angular materials

Tags: angular

To avoid importing modules from angular materials I created a separate angular module `AppCustomMaterialModule` and imported it in the main module `AppModule`. A component of that main module (`AppMenuComponent`) should use one of the exported angular materials modules. However, although the `AppCustomMaterialModule` is imported in `AppModule` it cannot be found in `AppMenuComponent`. A direct import works. Error message: 
`Module ...app-custom-material-module/app-custom-material.module' has no exported member 'MatMenuTrigger'`
What would I need to do to use the `AppCustomMaterialModule` as intended?

Structure:

```
|____app
| |____app.component.html
| |____app.component.ts
| |____app.component.spec.ts
| |____app.module.ts
| |____app-custom-material-module
| | |____app-custom-material.module.ts
| |____app-menu
| | |____app-menu.component.html
| | |____app-menu.component.spec.ts
| | |____app-menu.component.css
| | |____app-menu.component.ts
```

The AppCustomMaterialModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatMenuModule, MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatMenuTrigger
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatMenuTrigger
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppCustomMaterialModule { }
```

The main module "AppModule":

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppCustomMaterialModule } from './app-custom-material-module/app-custom-material.module';
import { AppMenuComponent } from './app-menu/app-menu.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppCustomMaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The component "AppMenuComponent":

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
// import { MatMenuTrigger } from "@angular/material/menu"; <== direct import works
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '../app-custom-material-module/app-custom-material.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './app-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-menu.component.css']
})
export class AppMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the Angular module imports array and the ES 2015 imports statement.

By using the shared module (AppCustomMaterialModule), you then don't need to add each Material Design Module to the imports array of each Angular module that needs it. As you've seen, you can simply add AppCustomMaterialModule to the imports array.

The ES 2015 imports statement has nothing to do with any of this. You still need to import each class that you will use in every file. This is a requirement of JavaScript (not Angular specifically).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I think that is as well described in [Angular Bootstrapping - The imports array](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping). However, like described in [Getting started - Step 3: Import the component modules](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) I'd like to avoid all the import statements. So in my components I would like to avoid importing all classes needed. Would that not be possible? If not then what is the intention of that section in the angular material getting started section? I may have misunderstood that part then.

Comment: No, as far as I know it is not possible to skip the import *statements*. In reading the Step 3 that you linked to, it clearly shows the imports *array*, not the import *statements*. The Import *statement* is a JavaScript feature as detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much for your help! Found as well an [example of of usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804438/importing-a-lot-of-modules-in-angular) - which was given by you, too :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't import MenuTrigger its not module. You can see angular [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#angular-ngmodule-names) and naming convention. File names are self describing.Imports array are only for modules.